# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Request failed with status code 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, crud

I'm trying to learn MERN/CRUD but running into an issue when I attempt to POST to my database. Trying to reach it via Insomniac gives me a 'cannot POST /users' error, and the console gives me a 'Unhandled Rejection (Error): Request failed with status code 404' error.

**app.js**

```
let express = require('express'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    dbConfig = require('./database/db'),
    cors = require('cors');

const userRoute = require('./routes/user.route');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Connection established with database...') }, 
    error => { console.log(`Error when connecting to database: ${error}`); 
})

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.use('/users', userRoute);

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Successfully connected on port: ${port}`)
});
```

Part of **create-user-component.js**

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const userObject = {
        firstName: this.state.firstName,
        lastName: this.state.lastName,
        email: this.state.email
    };

    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users', userObject)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data));

    this.setState({ firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '' });
}
```

**user.route.js**

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

let userSchema = require('../models/User');

// CREATE/POST User

router.route('/users').post((req, res, next) => {
    userSchema.create(req.body, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        return next(error)
      } else {
        console.log(data)
        res.json(data)
      }
    })
  });

router.route('/users').get((req, res) => {
    userSchema.find((error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            return next(error);
        } else {
            res.json(data);
        }
    })
})

router.route('/users/:id').get((req, res) => {
    userSchema.findById(req.params.id, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            return next(error);
        } else {
            res.json(data);
        }
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try like this ? By removing `users` statement from routes. Since you already defined it in `app.use('/users', userRoute);`, all routes defined in users.route.js will start with `users` by default.

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

let userSchema = require('../models/User');

// CREATE/POST User

router.route('/').post((req, res, next) => {
    userSchema.create(req.body, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        return next(error)
      } else {
        console.log(data)
        res.json(data)
      }
    })
  });

router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    userSchema.find((error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            return next(error);
        } else {
            res.json(data);
        }
    })
})

router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
    userSchema.findById(req.params.id, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            return next(error);
        } else {
            res.json(data);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! I guess I didn't catch that it was routing to /users/users. Thank you!